# How long can uncooked brisket be refrigerated after defrosting?

Tags: vacuum, thawing, brisket

I purchased a vac packed piece of brisket from Aldi a week ago. I froze it a day after buying, then thawed it in the fridge 2 days ago until it felt soft to touch. I opened the pack, washed it under faucet, patted it dry with paper towel and covered in rich crust of spices.  I don`t really feel anymore like cooking it today, and would prefer to do it tomorrow. Am I running a risk here of having this piece of meat spoil or develop something nasty while it sits in the fridge (not vac packed anymore, but still) for the 3rd day in a row?

Answer (score 2):

I believe 3-5 days is the basic guidance for keeping raw, defrosted whole cuts of meat in the refrigerator (See FoodSafety.gov).  Packaging has nothing to do with this.  Temperature is critical (below 40F...and colder is always better). I would say you are fine.